# Как сделать круглый прогресс бар на чистом css без javascript?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать круглый прогресс бар на чистом css, без использования js

Comment: Это так не работает. Покажите ваш код, как сами пытались сделать.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov а как можно показать код, если изначально не иметь ни малейшего представления, как это делается? div с border-radius'ом, что ли?

Comment: @andreymal не важно как это делается. важно как вы пытаетесь это сделать. но тут даже попыток не было - автор хочет готовое решение.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov по-моему на подобные вопросы невозможно ответить никак иначе, кроме как готовым решением. Задача достаточно узкая, это не какое-нибудь «как мне сделать социальную сеть»

Comment: Что есть "прогресс бар" в вашем понимании? Это же некая фиговина (если грубо), которая показывает динамику какого-либо процесса, она должна все время меняться, а для этого нужен js.

Comment: @Dmitry менять может и сервер путём отдачи модифицированной html-страницы, например

Comment: @andreymal Я-то в курсе, но в этом случае задача сводится к банальному "как нарисовать полоску заданной длины".

Comment: @Dmitry нарисовать *круглую* полоску заданной длины не так уж и банально)

Comment: @andreymal А, ну да, просили же "чистый css". Я автоматом подумал про svg - там таки достаточно банально.

Answer (score 4):

### Google творит чудеса:

*Без использования **JavaScript**, чистый **CSS*** :)

```css
.circle.left {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 100px, 100px, 50px);
}

.circle.right {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
}

.circle span {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border: 10px solid #5cb16e;
}

.circle.left span {
    clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
    -webkit-animation: rotate-left 5s  linear;
}

.circle.right span {
    clip: rect(0, 100px, 100px, 50px);
    -webkit-animation: rotate-right 5s  linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-left {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-right {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
 

/* counter */
.radial {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}
div.loop {
    position: relative;
    width: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 10%;
    top: 37px;
}
div.loop:after {
  content: attr(data-val);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: loop 10s ;
  animation: loop 10s ;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop {
  0% { margin-top: 0px; }
  9% { margin-top: 0px; }
  10% { margin-top: -20px; }
  19% { margin-top: -20px; }
  20% { margin-top: -40px; }
  29% { margin-top: -40px; }
  30% { margin-top: -60px; }
  39% { margin-top: -60px; }
  40% { margin-top: -80px; }
  49% { margin-top: -80px; }
  50% { margin-top: -100px; }
  59% { margin-top: -100px; }
  60% { margin-top: -120px; }
  69% { margin-top: -120px; }
  70% { margin-top: -140px; }
  79% { margin-top: -140px; }
  80% { margin-top: -160px; }
  89% { margin-top: -160px; }
  90% { margin-top: -180px; }
  99% { margin-top: -180px; }
  100% { margin-top: -200px; }
}

@keyframes loop {
  0% { margin-top: 0px; }
  9% { margin-top: 0px; }
  10% { margin-top: -20px; }
  19% { margin-top: -20px; }
  20% { margin-top: -40px; }
  29% { margin-top: -40px; }
  30% { margin-top: -60px; }
  39% { margin-top: -60px; }
  40% { margin-top: -80px; }
  49% { margin-top: -80px; }
  50% { margin-top: -100px; }
  59% { margin-top: -100px; }
  60% { margin-top: -120px; }
  69% { margin-top: -120px; }
  70% { margin-top: -140px; }
  79% { margin-top: -140px; }
  80% { margin-top: -160px; }
  89% { margin-top: -160px; }
  90% { margin-top: -180px; }
  99% { margin-top: -180px; }
  100% { margin-top: -200px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="radial">
    <div class="circle left rotate"><span></span></div>
    <div class="circle right rotate"><span></span></div>
    
    <div class="loop" data-val="1  2  3  4  5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: конечно круто , но каким образом здесь играет роль `data-val` ?

Comment: В прикол. А так не видно в примере да?

Comment: я вижу в html  а в css нет и потому не могу понять `как это работает`

Comment: content: attr(data-val);    [css-content-attr](https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr)

Comment: точно точно ... спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Обычные:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-container">


<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-grey" style="height:24px;width:25%"></div>
</div><br>

<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-grey" style="height:24px;width:50%"></div>
</div><br>

<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-grey" style="height:24px;width:75%"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Цветные:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-container">


<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-green" style="height:24px;width:25%"></div>
</div><br>

<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-red" style="height:24px;width:50%"></div>
</div><br>

<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-blue" style="height:24px;width:75%"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

С обозначением:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-container">


<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:25%">25%</div>
</div><br>

<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-center" style="width:50%">50%</div>
</div><br>

<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-container w3-blue" style="width:75%">75%</div>
</div><br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

И разным закруглением(те которые вам нужны):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<Br><Br>
<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round">
    <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round" style="width:25%">25%</div>
  </div><br>

  <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-large">
    <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-large" style="width:25%">25%</div>
  </div><br>

  <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
    <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-xlarge" style="width:25%">25%</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Думаю автор имел в виду что-то типа циферблата часов...

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Таких в интернете миллионы, стоит только поискать. А в вопросе какие именно прогрессбары не говорилось, просто круглые.

Comment: а зачем вы мне это говорите? Автору скажите, чтобы поискал.